# Label a specific node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

So, thanks to a user on her I managed to make a few graphs but I ran into a problem - why does:

```
\node at (a.corner 2) {$x_2$};
```

put the label $x_2$ in the center and not by the node? Many thanks.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]
         \path
            (0, 0)
            \foreach \i in {0, ..., 15} {
              +(360/16 * \i:3cm) coordinate (corner \i)
            }
          ;
          \draw[red]
            (corner 2) \foreach \i in {4,6, ..., 14,0} { -- (corner \i) }
            (corner 9) \foreach \i in {11,13,15,1,3,5} { -- (corner \i) }
          ;
          \draw[densely dashed]
            (corner 0) -- (corner 5)
            (corner 2) -- (corner 9)
          ;
          \fill[radius=2pt] \foreach \i in {0, ..., 15} { (corner \i) circle[]       };
          \node at (a.corner 2) {$x_2$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If that is the full code, there is something wrong, because there is no node called `a`, so you get an error saying `No shape named a is known.` Edit: In other words, try `\node [right] at (corner 2) {$x_2$};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, I imported the tikz positioning package and used:

```
\node [right=1mm of corner 1] {$x_2$};
```